# Sudoku: Stuck, Need hint to move forward

Tags: sudoku

I have applied the techniques I know to eliminate possible candidates. I'm stuck at this stage now, any hints to move forward are appreciated.

I found this puzzle in Microsoft sudoku Android app.

[image: Microsoft Sudoku _ Grandmaster Level]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The bottom row, seventh column, has two options: a 3 and a 7.
>  If it's a 3 (red), you can fill the 8 and 7 above, and then the 1 and 9 in the bottom left 3x3, so the bottom left corner is a 4.
>  If it's a 7 (green), you can fill the 4 in the bottom row, third column.
>  Therefore, the 4 in the bottom row cannot be in the fourth column, and that cell must be a 9.
>  [image]

Comment: Thank you, with this I could solve it completely. Wow, I still have so much left to learn.